# syntax for curl command not clear

Tags: xcode, curl

I am trying to download an html page as text file by executing the "curl" command under XCODE (Mac).

I already do that with the "wget" command under windows environment (Borland) and it is working well.
I am basically trying to run the same cpp code under XCODE environment by replacing the "wget" command with "curl" command.
Perhaps, as additional info, I use the "curl" for downloading some other link under XCODE and it is working fine, but I get problems only with this kind of link:

for executing this command I do the following:

```
// let's copy the command to a string
char string[] = "curl -o FileOut.txt \"https://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_cumulativereturn/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EUR&idtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=1970-01-01&performanceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F000000RTP]2]0]FOITA2792ALL&decPlaces=8&applyTrackRecordExtension=true%20-%20Cerca%20con%20Google\"";

// lets execute the command
system (string);
```

after executing the curl command the output contains just 14 bytes:  "`<TimeSeries />`". instead of the whole data.

As far as I have understood in other treads I should add the \ character before the & characters, maybe also before the : characters.
I have also added the " to the string array at the beginning and end of the link, but it doesn't help.

if I try to copy and paste this link to the browser I perfectly see the data (and I see also the data in my windows environment downloaded to the output file).

[https://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_cumulativereturn/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EUR&idtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=1970-01-01&performanceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F000000RTP]2]0]FOITA2792ALL&decPlaces=8&applyTrackRecordExtension=true%20-%20Cerca%20con%20Google](https://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_cumulativereturn/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EUR&idtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=1970-01-01&performanceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F000000RTP%5D2%5D0%5DFOITA2792ALL&decPlaces=8&applyTrackRecordExtension=true%20-%20Cerca%20con%20Google)

Comment: I'm not sure that the c++ tag applies.

Comment: If I try that in the terminal, I get "unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 206:". This looks like a curl issue, and you should read its manual.

Comment: If you use `[]{}` in the URL, curl will use those for "globbing". Switch off globbing with `-g`. If you would've tried your command line in a shell and read the error text, you could've deduced this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, that's awesome!

I got the right solution thanks to molbdnilo and Daniel feedbacks!

It was related to the bracket message error and the use of -g option that, honestly, I still don't understand what is that.

I will read the documentation of the curl command (I did already before) but honestly, I am wondering how you all can understand the help... sometimes it is really hard for me to understand what they are talking about !
Well, Im a newbie, maybe that's why :)

Many thanks again, topic is considered closed !

Oh, as last, I had to add \" into the string (beginning and end) to let the string passed to the curl command include  two  ""  characters.

Grazie ! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
char string[] = "curl -o FileOut.txt https://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_cumulativereturn/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EUR&idtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=1970-01-01&performanceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F000000RTP]2]0]FOITA2792ALL&decPlaces=8&applyTrackRecordExtension=true%20-%20Cerca%20con%20Google";

system (string);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
unfortunately that's exactly what I already did, but it doesn't work.  
I have read somewhere that there are problem with special characters, I should add the backslash in the string before these characters, I tried but I didn't get anything working.
But when using  "simple" links, where special characters are not present, it downloads the page without problems.  Im stuck on it....